# Use entries from two tables to select data from a third table

Tags: mysql

I want to filter out data from a main table containing cities and zip codes, by parsing entries in two other tables.

I'll give an example, to help explain what I want to do.

Below is the table I want to filter data from.
Lets call this table Cities.

| Zip | City |
| --- | --- |
| 0001 | New York |
| 0002 | New York |
| 0003 | Washington |
| 0004 | Los Angeles |
| 0005 | San Francisco |

Now, I also have this table - called Customers:

| Zip | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 0004 | John Appleseed |
| 0004 | Gary Appleseed |
| 0003 | Betsy Appleseed |
| 0004 | George Appleseed |
| 0005 | Anna Appleseed |

And finally, my third table is called Employees:

| Zip | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 0005 | John Doe |
| 0002 | Gary Doe |
| 0002 | Betsy Doe |
| 0004 | George Doe |
| 0005 | Anna Doe |

What I want to do is to list the name of each City from the Cities table where I have no Employees or Customers registered from the other two tables.

What throws me is that we see that New York has two Zip codes, and while no Customers or Employees live in the 0001 zip code, I have entries that match the 0002 zip code so I want to make sure not to filter out New York by mistake.

Comment: So you want an empty result? That's not usually very useful when constructing a sample data set

Comment: I'm a bit tired so I messed up the sample set, but the accepted answer worked on the real dataset that I'm working on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is some what more complicated, as you first need the zip of all cities thta has no correspndens in customer or employee and then you must also exclue all cities that have a such a person

> ```
> CREATE TABLE cities (
>   `Zip` INTEGER,
>   `City` VARCHAR(13)
> );
>
> INSERT INTO cities
>   (`Zip`, `City`)
> VALUES
>   ('0001', 'New York'),
>   ('0002', 'New York'),
>   ('0003', 'Washington'),
>   ('0004', 'Los Angeles'),
>   ('0005', 'San Francisco');
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE customers (
>   `Zip` INTEGER,
>   `Name` VARCHAR(16)
> );
>
> INSERT INTO customers
>   (`Zip`, `Name`)
> VALUES
>   ('0004', 'John Appleseed'),
>   ('0004', 'Gary Appleseed'),
>   ('0003', 'Betsy Appleseed'),
>   ('0004', 'George Appleseed'),
>   ('0005', 'Anna Appleseed');
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE employees (
>   `Zip` INTEGER,
>   `Name` VARCHAR(10)
> );
>
> INSERT INTO employees
>   (`Zip`, `Name`)
> VALUES
>   ('0005', 'John Doe'),
>   ('0002', 'Gary Doe'),
>   ('0002', 'Betsy Doe'),
>   ('0004', 'George Doe'),
>   ('0005', 'Anna Doe');
> ```

> ```
> SELECT DISTINCT `City` 
> FROM cities 
> WHERE (`Zip` NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT `Zip` FROM customers) 
> OR `Zip` NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT `Zip` FROM employees))
> AND `City`  NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT `City` 
> FROM cities 
> WHERE `Zip` IN (SELECT DISTINCT `Zip` FROM customers) 
> OR `Zip` IN (SELECT DISTINCT `Zip` FROM employees))
> ```
>
> ```
> | City |
> | :--- |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=75ab70e1e17998c0b114994f30c0a6af)*

Comment: This seems less verbose... https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=acec56c172859a1e441e1e58b4fd13de

Comment: This was a brilliant answer, thanks, only edit I had to make was to remove the single quotation marks in front of the column names in order to get it working on my end.